# Dired: Insert/Moved to this subir for all subdirs?

Tags: dired

windows 10, emacs 25.1, dired+

In dired mode if I want to open subfolder in the same folder as parent folder I press `i`

Here example:

[image]

OK. It's work fine.

But if folder has many subfolder I need to press `i` for every subfolder. It's work but it very slow.

Question: Is it possible to open ALL subfolders in the one buffer by press only one key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

1. Mark all directories: **`* /`** (command `dired-mark-directories`).
2. Use **`M-i`** (command `diredp-insert-subdirs`) to insert all of the marked directories.

---

You can also insert subdirectories in a recursive way (subsubdirs, subsubsubdirs, etc.).

To do that, you use **`M-+ M-i`** (command `diredp-insert-subdirs-recursive`).

Like other directory-recursive commands (they are all on prefix key `M-+`), this acts on files in the marked directories, gathered recursively, or, with a prefix arg, on **ALL** files in all directories, gathered recursively. In this case, the files it acts on are just directories, themselves.

So to insert all of the marked directories and their subdirectories (recursively), use `M-+ M-i`.  And to insert *all* directories and their subdirectories (recursively), use `C-u M-+ M-i`.